# Openembedded: How to add python-robotframework to Yocto

Tags: python, yocto, openembedded

I search describing hints to include python-robotframework into openembedded project and can someone tell good instruction how to proceed?

I'm using rocko-fslc-4.9.11-mx6ul-v1.0 release on ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

So far so good and after first bitbake I added *" python python-robotframework"* to **local.conf** and run bitbake again, but robotframework didn't appear.  I have searched it by next command:

```
-VirtualBox:~/var-fslc-yocto/build_x11$ bitbake -e python-robotframework | grep ^PACKAGECONFIG
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'python-robotframework'. Close matches: python-robotparser
```

Next set of lines has been tried on **local.conf**: bitbake goes through with every option without expected result.

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL  + =  ” python-meta python-robotframework”
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL  =  ” python-meta python-robotframework”
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL ? =  ” python-meta python-robotframework”
IMAGE_INSTALL += “ python python-robotframework”
```

So, I have studied answers related add python modules into OE, but I'm still lost how to proceed. Does anyone included robotframework into OE?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `python-robotframework` is first available in the Sumo release, but not in Rocko.
(You can easily search for packages here: http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=robotframework)

So your options are either backporting the recipe to Rocko or upgrading to Sumo.

By the way: You have to add the meta-python layer to your bblayers.conf if you haven't already done this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers!

bblayers.conf file had already python-meta layer so backporting needed.
I downloaded recipes one by one from gitgub: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-python/ 
with next downloading hints see youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIJdfuAoqFI

Then editing local.conf file:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = ” python python-robotframework”
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = ” python python3-robotframework”
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = ” python python-robotframeworkseriallibrary”
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = ” python python3-robotframeworkseriallibrary”
```

After this ***bitbake*** works fine and I saw robotframework related recipes.